# iPhone App Crashes on App Store build but not on Development build

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graphics

So here's the story.

I submit the [app](http://bit.ly/getdefinition) to the App Store and before I do so, I check for bugs on devices (iPhone, iPod and iPad) and simulator.

When I download the app from the App Store, it crashes while opening. It is strange enough that it is happening on only 50% of the devices. Furthermore, it is even stranger that Apple allows the updates since I'm sure they do test it on their device first.

Taking a look at the crash logs has pointed me to GraphicsServices: GSEventRunModal which I have no idea what it is. Symbolicating it shows: "start (in Definition) + 44". What's the start method?

I really need help at this stage, since I have been over the problem for months and it's been the same bug. I've been looking over at the code but to no avail. Could this be a graphics problem? If so, how can I fix it?

Here's a crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: D810A911-0B5C-4040-95F0-8EF7B4050C94
CrashReporter Key:   e382b2b61059a00922424c48f525d92eaadf1606
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         Definition [3644]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F5405DCA-3B4D-4190-B472-86FDBA764CC7/Definition.app/Definition
Identifier:      Definition
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-04-13 21:23:12.834 +0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.1 (8G4)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df4a1c 0x34de3000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4c3b4 0x32a19000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a44bf8 0x32a19000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3467ca64 0x34638000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x301cd06c 0x301c7000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3467ae36 0x34638000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3467ae8a 0x34638000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3467af5a 0x34638000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x301cbc84 0x301c7000 + 19588
9   Foundation                      0x344fb924 0x3446c000 + 588068
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35afba72 0x35a86000 + 481906
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35afd69c 0x35a86000 + 489116
12  CoreFoundation                  0x35afe4e4 0x35a86000 + 492772
13  CoreFoundation                  0x35a8eebc 0x35a86000 + 36540
14  CoreFoundation                  0x35a8edc4 0x35a86000 + 36292
15  GraphicsServices                0x354ae418 0x354aa000 + 17432
16  GraphicsServices                0x354ae4c4 0x354aa000 + 17604
17  UIKit                           0x356f5d62 0x356c7000 + 191842
18  UIKit                           0x356f3800 0x356c7000 + 182272
19  Definition                      0x0000247a 0x1000 + 5242
20  Definition                      0x00002410 0x1000 + 5136

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df53ec 0x34de3000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4d6d8 0x32a19000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4dbbc 0x32a19000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df5fbc 0x34de3000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x32dfa094 0x32df4000 + 24724
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x32dfb04a 0x32df4000 + 28746
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x32dfa60a 0x32df4000 + 26122
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4d58a 0x32a19000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4dbbc 0x32a19000 + 215996

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df53ec 0x34de3000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4d6d8 0x32a19000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4dbbc 0x32a19000 + 215996

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df2c00 0x34de3000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df2758 0x34de3000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35afc2b8 0x35a86000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35afe562 0x35a86000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35a8eebc 0x35a86000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35a8edc4 0x35a86000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x33bf6292 0x33bf0000 + 25234
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4c30a 0x32a19000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4dbb4 0x32a19000 + 215988

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df2c00 0x34de3000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df2758 0x34de3000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35afc2b8 0x35a86000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35afe562 0x35a86000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35a8eebc 0x35a86000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35a8edc4 0x35a86000 + 36292
6   Foundation                      0x344967f6 0x3446c000 + 174070
7   Foundation                      0x34489382 0x3446c000 + 119682
8   Foundation                      0x344fb5c6 0x3446c000 + 587206
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4c30a 0x32a19000 + 209674
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4dbb4 0x32a19000 + 215988

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df53ec 0x34de3000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4d6d8 0x32a19000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4dbbc 0x32a19000 + 215996

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df4c60 0x34de3000 + 72800
1   CoreFoundation                  0x35b018f2 0x35a86000 + 506098
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4c30a 0x32a19000 + 209674
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4dbb4 0x32a19000 + 215988

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df2c00 0x34de3000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34df2758 0x34de3000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35afc2b8 0x35a86000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35afe562 0x35a86000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35a8eebc 0x35a86000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35ad16d2 0x35a86000 + 308946
6   Definition                      0x00013a34 0x1000 + 76340
7   Foundation                      0x34489382 0x3446c000 + 119682
8   Foundation                      0x344fb5c6 0x3446c000 + 587206
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4c30a 0x32a19000 + 209674
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32a4dbb4 0x32a19000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3e6cc48c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0022905c      r7: 0x2fdfe9a0
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0023a6f0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe994      lr: 0x32a4c3bb      pc: 0x34df4a1c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x8efff +Definition armv7  <b90bffca1ee3fcfd184ab6f9391b56ce> /var/mobile/Applications/F5405DCA-3B4D-4190-B472-86FDBA764CC7/Definition.app/Definition
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <8dbdf7bab30e355b81e7b2e333d5459b> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30165000 - 0x3016efff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x301b3000 - 0x301b8fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x301c7000 - 0x3028bfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <f855251d90a53bdbb5d5a39fdbde6d9b> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x303ba000 - 0x303bafff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x303ff000 - 0x3041ffff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3044e000 - 0x3049cfff  CoreMotion armv7  <8660c1394c5c39089407c07fd7fd8b52> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x304a0000 - 0x304e3fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <01a5c5442e173624bdbde3c1f4ad4665> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x304e4000 - 0x3052cfff  CoreLocation armv7  <90a87c2cdf823e6892aff81a6dde3430> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x30531000 - 0x30568fff  Security armv7  <163414ba17df347ca76088015010e2c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30614000 - 0x30614fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x30630000 - 0x30663fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x306d7000 - 0x306e5fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f02d1c50f0f33991adb1a2caed02eb77> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x30708000 - 0x3078cfff  AVFoundation armv7  <9d5e43475961327384d6218d14de8b1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3078d000 - 0x307cdfff  CoreMedia armv7  <0fcb3d1136d033d3acd97519c4be3ac3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x307d9000 - 0x307dcfff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x309ed000 - 0x30b41fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x30bed000 - 0x30bfdfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <6956561235333e74b8ff316cb2edc93e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x30c0a000 - 0x30c50fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <4319daea186b3a22b148ca78000f11ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x30c51000 - 0x30c5bfff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30c5c000 - 0x30c72fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9776dd6c96b531e9885bddacd2a8adb1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30ce6000 - 0x30ceafff  libcache.dylib armv7  <36e96d0a7dda330281a43172d0ada49a> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x30cf4000 - 0x30d45fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x30d46000 - 0x30d4efff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x30e30000 - 0x30f4afff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x30f77000 - 0x30f78fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x30fca000 - 0x32a18fff  TextInput armv7  <f242acc046073c1598195dd26fd8ad6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x32a19000 - 0x32a9afff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <caa1846ad2583d1b84c1a15c50c126a2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x32df0000 - 0x32df3fff  ActorKit armv7  <f7aa6cdd654231988aafcf448978f450> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x32df4000 - 0x32e01fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <6c4eeb08757b365f8429ef6747f89ad3> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x32e02000 - 0x32e1ffff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x32e26000 - 0x32e4ffff  ContentIndex armv7  <f5a3613ec5b6392995d7ed0742f7419f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x32e50000 - 0x32e8dfff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32ea5000 - 0x32ed3fff  MIME armv7  <28e35d5e19893de6bc28463efec5222f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x32eed000 - 0x32ff5fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32ff9000 - 0x33018fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x33019000 - 0x33051fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x33052000 - 0x33085fff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x33086000 - 0x33086fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <68322643de8030978c862de530055bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x33286000 - 0x33323fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x33324000 - 0x33327fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x33328000 - 0x33341fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33342000 - 0x33349fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3334a000 - 0x3334cfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33586000 - 0x3358bfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <1eaf25ddd98e3a249bca536671c5819d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x335b0000 - 0x335e3fff  StoreServices armv7  <a74659288dea34bca7a7911c19cf2c28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x335e4000 - 0x335e9fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3364e000 - 0x33657fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33679000 - 0x336bbfff  CoreAudio armv7  <d45e275525ef3c32b36e0f1020cad705> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33725000 - 0x3374efff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3374f000 - 0x337f8fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x337ff000 - 0x33806fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x33921000 - 0x33950fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x33957000 - 0x33966fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <f258d39dc7d93faa9c9ff5cf81c5dcbd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x33967000 - 0x33974fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x339d4000 - 0x33b00fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x33b07000 - 0x33b16fff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x33b19000 - 0x33b19fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x33b1d000 - 0x33b20fff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x33b91000 - 0x33beffff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d3f7360687333cad987890c314ae0d6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33bf0000 - 0x341fbfff  WebCore armv7  <b25d7d87ebd235ecbceca611a063c73b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x34200000 - 0x3420bfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3425d000 - 0x34266fff  ITSync armv7  <dc57c003aad83864827ccf95fc579563> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x3427e000 - 0x342d3fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x342d4000 - 0x3435efff  Message armv7  <1e4680ca7d4936bf9f575269b67e4402> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x3446c000 - 0x3458bfff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34638000 - 0x34682fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x34683000 - 0x34685fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x34686000 - 0x34687fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x346a4000 - 0x34713fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x34743000 - 0x34753fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x34754000 - 0x34805fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x34806000 - 0x3480bfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <a19b1caf96c73568b14a1660f147ae2f> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x34816000 - 0x348bcfff  Celestial armv7  <6a54406a081a3b5fa6b22754b013b629> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x349c5000 - 0x34ab2fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x34bcd000 - 0x34c02fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34c0e000 - 0x34c12fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34c15000 - 0x34c17fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c0617d2a41283cc2bff1a1d770c06f8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x34c18000 - 0x34c54fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <79d00adb09de3da991ed21f48f27adb4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34ca0000 - 0x34ca1fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x34db5000 - 0x34db7fff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x34dc4000 - 0x34dd0fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x34de3000 - 0x34dfafff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <29eb602b615b3c3b95722868100a2d1c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x34e0c000 - 0x34e1ffff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x35145000 - 0x35146fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x35148000 - 0x3514dfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x35223000 - 0x3525bfff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x35269000 - 0x3526cfff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <0479a171c00d3f629d639713acb72b5b> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3526d000 - 0x35282fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3535b000 - 0x35389fff  DataAccess armv7  <3a2e67aa1d8834b7a8fc2fbb56654b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x3538a000 - 0x3538bfff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x35394000 - 0x353edfff  EventKit armv7  <0d4e597ee229337183e96e921a72e30a> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x353f0000 - 0x3549ffff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x354aa000 - 0x354b6fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c508734deb43352782433a290ff235bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3557d000 - 0x355cbfff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x355cc000 - 0x355ecfff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x355ed000 - 0x3560dfff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x3562b000 - 0x3562dfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35635000 - 0x35674fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <b5735b0f3dba32c087c5b58aa48ae592> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x35675000 - 0x3567bfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x35683000 - 0x356b7fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <aec2e22a2055380e82d4d0279faad0a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x356c7000 - 0x35a54fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35a84000 - 0x35a85fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <5f077c4d204d3cd7b04452c42d41f763> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x35a86000 - 0x35b6bfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <4f643539f91f330790f112ea7150b3a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35b9c000 - 0x35b9ffff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35bd1000 - 0x35bd3fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35db1000 - 0x35df8fff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x35e02000 - 0x35e02fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x35e9c000 - 0x36183fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <652c97e211553d4e84968a61f62a0ac5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x36184000 - 0x36188fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <2c61a8f7e7bf32d890e957d768d769ce> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x36189000 - 0x362d5fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <7b1ac06abad33dca99a29629b667f929> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x362db000 - 0x36370fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x36371000 - 0x36430fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36478000 - 0x3647ffff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36480000 - 0x36486fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x364ee000 - 0x36500fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <8de1cf029f8132a2946ccca351dbd4fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x36656000 - 0x36777fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <54e27b8aa66c32b48ffeadadcc514331> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x367c3000 - 0x368c7fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <f63386018d703534b766514e4bbbd1d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x368c8000 - 0x368fbfff  iCalendar armv7  <e52c54abaab734e8b0278f358217c4b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
```

Comment: You need to post your crash log.  WHat version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Nice looking app! I would have purchased had you not mentioned the crashing issue :)

Comment: Using XCode 4, previously on XCode 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this as a problem as well in my past.

- Make sure you are targeting the release to the same architecture. (armv6/armv7)
- Make sure you are targeting the right version of iOS.

You could always test with an ad-hoc release.

*Aside*: I found this to be quite frustrating with the approval process... you think Apple would catch this...

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate on your first point?

"Make sure you are targeting the release to the same architecture."

Comment: I've set it for Standard (armv6/armv7) which never changed since the beginning. Should be correct?

Comment: make sure both release and debug are that way.

Comment: Are there any similarities between the devices it crashes on? This log says iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3.1. Maybe a model/iOS version issue?

Answer (score 0):

On what iOS version(s) did you test the app with? And on what iOS version(s) does it crash? Depending on that you can check if you may have used any functions that may not be available for those iOS versions.

Comment: It crashes on every iOS version, oddly.

Comment: Are there any warnings when you build your app? You may want to look at those. Also, I believe (looking at your question) that it doesn't crash when you run in debug mode on your device. Right?

Comment: Nope no warnings. I've made the effort to ensure it doesn't crash on debug/release build on all my devices!